# IE8 issue with PNG images (rotation and reflection)

Tags: internet-explorer, png

A curious problem here. I'm testing a site using [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) for Internet Explorer 8. I'm using a couple of PNG (PNG-24) files but they appear rotated 180 degrees and reflected 90 degrees.

Surely it's known issue, how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would verify that the issue is really with IE8 and not IETester. I would run it quickly through http://browsershots.org/ or http://browsercam.com

Comment: I wish I were able to do that, but my system was updated automatically to IE9 (I know, that's a very good thing). Do you know of any other IE tester out there?

Comment: Yes, it seems this is an IETester issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fix that with the browser, especially IE is not good doing nice things with CSS. You have to rotate and flip it with, for example, Adobe FireWorks.

Comment: Not sure I understood what you meant. IE9 works fine, but IE8 is doing that weird rotation/reflection thing. Obviously, that's a bug that needs to be addressed within CSS.

Comment: That is the strange world that is called IE8, it is a old version. See also answer from Ted. I have seen that IE using different render engine for compatibility mode. For example IE8 compatibility mode renders differently comparing to the 'original' product version of IE8. So it is possible that IETester do things differently, that is why it is beter to use the orginal version instead.

Comment: I remember that IE7/IE8 has problems with 24-bit png's. Maybe you have to downgrade it to a lower color resolution.